# How to remove the hold on a question which has been flagged as too broad?

Tags: discussion, support

[What kind of qualitative and quantitative analysis are done during user research of the empathize phase of design thinking?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/110659/105224)

I have edited the question to make it much more specific, but I am not sure how i can remove the hold on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The act of editing an On Hold question automatically adds it into the review queue for 'reopen voting'. That is what happened to your question, and it was unanimously voted to remain closed.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/46509

It is still too broad a question to answer with one single, correct answer. You're really asking for examples of things that you can then take your pick from 'what kind of analysis are ideal...'. That's too big a question, and really would be something that whole books would cover rather than a single Q&A post.